# process 1 table in hibernate with multithreads

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in a application using spring+hibernate.
I have a situation where I have to fetch a set of records from 1 table(with status flag 0), process each of them (will generate data for other tables), then set the status flag to 1.

problem is all of this is being done by 1 thread, and is very slow. I want to achieve lets say i make 10 threads. each of them will take one records, process, save, done. Then the process will speed up 10 times.
Pls look at picture. Any advise on how to do this?

---- current situation ----
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AirWL.jpg

------ desired situation ------
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsX0N.jpg

Comment: Can you post some source/config files? What do you mean by 'slow'? What is your current speed and what would be an acceptable speed? How are your requirements regarding transactions? You need all your updates to be atomic one by one or is a batch approach acceptable for you? (say only commit per 1000 records)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the process method in a `Runnable` and execute it using a `TaskExecutor`.
You can play with TaskExecutor parameters like thread pool size using the spring task namespace or annotations, at you choice.

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: thanks, my situation is like this, 
there already a thread-pool of quartz schedule that keep trigger every lets day 5 sec. 

But if every 5 sec, the task get executed then the db will get mess up, so I use a atomicboolean variable to only allow one thread to run the task. 

But then that task will get all flag0 items (by hibernate) and does everything (thus slow). If I remove the atomicboolean, it can be happened that 2 quartz threads try to get all flag0 items and process them parallel. 

Any idea to synchonize that first thread only get first flag0 item, then 2nd thread get next flag0 item?